# Getting specific part of data from pivot table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I'm doing a website where companies have **persons** which have **scores** per **event**.
And the events are ordered by city.

So by example someone can do 4 events, so they get a score for each event.

I'm using a pivot table to save the scores. ( here's a screenshot )

[image]

Now i'm loading all persons for a certain event with the following query.

```
$data['companies'] = Event::find($id)->city->companies;
```

And i'm showing them using the following structure in my blade file

```
@foreach($companies as $company)
   {{ $company->name }}
        @foreach($company->persons as $person)
           {{ $person->firstname }}
           {{ $person->eventscore }}
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
```

### The person->eventscore is the link to the pivot table. And it's working but it's giving me the scores of that person for ALL the events.

I only want to see the score for the event that we are watching now ( you can see the id in the url bar, and i marked the id with a red arrow, Now how can i? In my view ask to only show to score for the specific event?

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There need to a little change in your query.. See the below example.

```
class Person extends Eloquent {
    public function events()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Event', 'person_event', 'event_id', 'person_id')->withPivot('id','score');
    }
}

class Event extends Eloquent {
    public function persons()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Person', 'person_event', 'person_id', 'event_id')->withPivot('id','score');
    }
}
```

Now to loading all persons for a certain event, query is ..

```
$event_id = 1;
$persons = Person::with('events')->whereHas('events', function($q) use ($event_id){$q->where('event_id',$event_id);})->get();
```

In view...

```
@foreach($persons->events as $event)
    {{ $event->pivot->score}}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify in your model or more specially in your relation which pivot fields you want.

Here is just an example which you can do

```
function events(){

return $this->belongsToMany('Events', 'person_events', 'person_id', 'event_id')->withPivot('score');

}
```

Now you can access this score calling pivot as follows.

```
@foreach($persons->events as $event)

    {{ $event->pivot->score}}

@endforeach
```

The above foreach loop is just iterating through all person events and getting the score of that specific event from pivot table.